# Logic game: maximising (or minimising) the chances for two agents to meet

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, logic

> **Note:** this question is tagged both **language-agnostic** and **python** as my primary concern is finding out the algorithm to implement the solution to the problem, but information on how to implement it *efficiently* (=executing fast!) in python are a plus.

**Rules of the game:**

- Imagine two teams one of *A agents* (`An`) and one of *B agents* (`Bn`).
- In the game space there are a certain number of available *slots* (`Sn`) that can be occupied.
- At each turn each agent is given a subset of slots he/she can occupy.
- One agent can occupy *only one slot at at time*, however each slot can be occupied by two different agents, provided they are *each from a different team*.

**The question:**

I am trying to find an ***efficient* way to compute the best possible move** for `A` agents,  where "best possible move" means either maximising or minimising the chances to occupy the same slots occupied by team `B`. The moves of team `B` are not known in advance.

**Example scenario:**

This scenario is deliberately trivial. It is just meant to illustrate the game mechanics.

```
A1 can occupy S1, S2
A2 can occupy S2, S3
B1 can occupy S1, S2
```

In this case the solution is obvious: `A1 → S1` and `A2 → S2` is the option that will guarantee meeting with `B1` [as `B1` cannot avoid to occupy either `S1` or `S2`], while `A2 → S3` and `A1 → random(S1, S2)` is the one that will maximise the chances to avoid `B1`.

**Real-life scenarios:**

In real-life scenarios, the slots can be hundreds and the agents in each team various dozens. The difficulty in the naïve implementation I tried so far is that I basically consider every single possible set of moves for the team `B`, and score each of the possible alternative set of moves for `A`. So, my computation time increases exponentially.

Still, I'm not sure this is a problem that can be solved only by "brute force". And even if this is the case I wonder:

1. If the optimal brute force solution necessarily grows exponentially (time-wise).
2. If there is a way to compute an non-optimal, locally-best solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know which slots each team can legally occupy each turn?  I.e. is this like a 2D map or something?

Comment: @Will Yes: at each turn I know who are the components of both teams and which are all their possible (legal) moves.

Comment: Btw, if they're moving around a map, do you necessarily even want to optimize each turn individually, or would it be a good trade-off for `A` to move an agent in a way that misses the `B` agents this turn, but sets up an opportunity to meet them the following turn that would not otherwise be available?

Comment: Also, I think it might make a difference whether you're trying to maximise (a) the probability of at least one meeting or (b) the expected number of meetings.

Comment: @SteveJessop - It would be a good trade-off to miss `B` now to increase chances of meeting it the following turn, but I feel that would deserve an entire new question. :) I am under the impression that that strategy would however relay on calculating the values as asked here first. **Am I wrong about that?** As for the second question: the complete game has a number of additional rules for which both would be a "best solution". **My priority is on finding (a), however... (b) is a plus!** :)

Comment: The moves of team B aren't known in advance, but is anything known about the strategy of team B? Do they move randomly, or could they actively try to avoid meeting team A?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber - Funny enough, I wrote a paragraph about this than I then did not post as I thought it was irrelevant. The answer: **team `B` is governed by another player but there is no way to know what his strategy is** (well, you can analyse previous moves to find out what his/her play style is... but that's also subject for another question!). [My conclusion was that - given the impossibility to know the strategy - it was the same than considering his moves random... Am I wrong about this?]

Comment: If you know nothing about his strategy, the moves might as well be random - that's the Bayesian interpretation of what random means. That's stronger than what you have in the question, though, which just says that the moves aren't known in advance; knowing that A wants to maximize meetings while B wants to avoid them provides a lot of information, while not telling you the moves of the other player.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Not necessarily. If `B` has an objective, then you can figure out his optimal strategy as well. For instance, if `B` is trying to minimize meetings and `A` is trying to maximize them, then both players should take both strategies into account.

Comment: @PengOne I don't see how that contradicts anything I wrote. If you know the objective for B, that says something (a lot, probably) about his strategy.

Comment: @Michael: just for fun, it also makes a difference whether B knows *your* objectives, and whether B knows whether you know whether B knows your objectives, and so on. I believe that usually in game theory, both players' objectives are held to be "common knowledge" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_%28logic%29), which is one of those things that people used to think was trivial but turns out to need quite a deep theoretical formulation. So this problem differs from the norm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The members of the two teams and the slots define a tripartite graph `A-S-B`, with edges given by the possible moves. The bipartite subgraphs consisting of the slots and members of just one team are of interest; call these `A-S` for the graph with team A members and `S-B` for team B members. You can use the `S-B` graph to assign values to the slots, and then the `S-A` graph to select moves that maximize or minimize the value for team A.

An appropriate choice for the value of a slot is the likelihood of finding a member of team B in that slot. With that, the value for a set of moves for team A is the sum of the slot values, i.e., the expected number of slots where a team B member will be found. Note that the moves of the members of a team are not independent, so both stages present some challenge.

Given the values for the slots, choosing the moves for team A becomes a standard problem: the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). This is related to the maximal bipartite matching suggested in missingno's answer, but the value of the slots needs to be accounted for; the edges can be given weight equal to the value of the slot on which the edge is incident, with a maximum weighted bipartite matching equivalent to the assignment problem. Use standard algorithms to solve (or approximate) this part of the problem.

So how can we assign values to the slots? I'd suggest just generating random moves for the members of team B,  counting how often the slots are occupied, and dividing the counts by the number of sample moves you consider. It's not really clear from the question how hard it will be to generate a random set of moves; assuming that each team member has the option to stay in place, it is easy to do just by randomly selecting moves for each member in random order.

A simplifying factor in both stages is that there is an easy way to decompose the problem into independent sub-problems. The connected components of the bipartite graphs show which team members can move in a way that interferes with which others, e.g., if the team members are split into two groups on different parts of the board, the groups can be treated independently. This applies in both stages, both probabilistically evaluating the slots with the `S-B` graph and optimizing the assignment in the `A-S` graph. Of course, if any component is small enough, you could always enumerate the possibilities and solve the subproblem exactly.

Comment: Thanks for this (+1). I already implemented the sub-division of the problem, but I did not mention it because - as far as I could see - the solution to the larger problem is just the sum of the solutions to the smaller ones (=no conceptual difference). The part about the assignment problem was however novel to me, and having found an algorithm that solves that part in O(n^3) instead of O(n!) has been like seeing the light at the end of the tunnel! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a brute force solution, but perhaps less brute than the obvious one of enumerating all possibilities. As noted by the other solutions, this problem has to do with [matchings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) on a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

**Step 1: Compute the probability of each site being occupied by a *B* agent**

Construct the following bipartite graph. The vertices are the *B* agents `B1,B2,...,BK` and the sites `S1,S2,...,SN`, and there is an edge between `Bi` and `Sj` if agent `Bi` can occupy site `Sj`. Find all maximal matchings (or maximum matchings if that's your algorithm for *B* agents) on this graph, say there are `M` of them. For each site `Si`, the probability of the site being occupied by a *B* agent is

```
Pi = #(matchings using Si) / M
```

*Algorithms to consider*:

- [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft-Karp_algorithm)

**Step 2: Find the highest weight matching for *A* agents**

Construct the following edge-weighted bipartite graph. The vertices are the *A* agents `A1,A2,...,AL` and the sites `S1,S2,...,SN`, and there is an edge between `Ai` and `Sj` if agent `Ai` can occupy site `Sj` and this edge has weight `Pi`. Find a maximum matching with maximal or minimal weight.

*Algorithms to consider*:

- [Bellman–Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm)
- [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra_algorithm)
- [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap)
- [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

Right now this is nothing more than a restatement of the problem, but perhaps thinking about it in this way will lead to a less brutish brute force approach. For example, once Step 1 is done, you can take a greedy algorithm to choose a play for *A* agents by including those `Si` with highest/lowest probability. Though finding matchings can be difficult, knowing whether or not one exists isn't. You can use [Hall's marriage theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_theorem) to determine whether a perfect matching exists once you choose the most/least likely `Si`s.

Comment: A true mine of leads to explore! Thanks and +1!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the problem of finding an optimal strategy for A once you know the positions for B is the same as finding a [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in a bipartite graph.

The first set of vertices represent the A agents, the second set of vertices represent the slots ocupyed by the B agents and there is an edge if an agent can choose the occupy the slot.

The problem is then finding the maximum number of edges you can ocupy without a vertex touching more then one edge.

There are simple polynomial algorithms to solve this problem. One of the most classic is the one based on [augmenting paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Maximum_cardinality_bipartite_matching).

```
while you can find a path, augment the path

a path is a sequence of vertices a1, b1, a2, b2, ... an, bn such that
  ai -> bi is an unmatched edge
  bi -> a(i+1) is a matched edge
  a1 and bn are unmatched

to augment a path
  match all the unmatched edges (ai -> bi)
  unmatch all the matched edges (bi -> a(i+1))
  (this results in one aditional matched edge after the iteration)
```

A naïve implementation of this algorithm is O(V*E) but you can probably find more efficient python implementations of bipartite matching somewhere.

Comment: I don't think this matches the problem description because in the OP the locations of the B agents are not known...

Comment: **Do I understand you correctly?** You are saying that - while I will have to iterate on all possible configuration of moves for `B` (the second set of vertex) there is a linear function to pick the best set of moves for `A`, without having to try them all. This should in turn mean that my computation time would be still growing exponentially, but only in relation to the numbers of agents and possible moves of the `B` team. If I understand you correctly, **could you please clarify further with a trivial example?** I'm having an hard time following the pseudo-code.

Answer (score -3):

This is not really a question of programming as much as it is a game theory question. What follows is a sketch of a game-theoretic analysis of the problem.

We have a game of two players (A and B). A two-player game is always a zero-sum game, i.e. the gain of one player is loss for the other. Even if game payoffs are not zero-sum (i.e. there are results that give positive payoffs to both players), payoffs can be always normalized (taking their difference), so we can assume without loss of generality that the game here is also a zero-sum game. From this we deduce that if it is the goal of A to maximize [minimize] the number of meetings with agents of B, then it is the goal of B to minimize [maximize] the number of meetings with agents of A.

Based on the description it is further assumed that A and B choose their moves simultaneously, i.e. A picks the slots for A's agents without knowing which slots B's agents are going to take and vice versa. Without this assumption, i.e. if B can see A's moves, it's very easy for B to "win".

Let X be the set of all possible assignments of A's agents to the available slots (obeying the constraints for the current round or turn), i.e. X is a set of subsets of the slots; every subset denoting an assignment of agents to exactly those slots in the subset. Similarly, let Y be the set of all possible assignment of B's agents to the available slots (similarly obeying the constraints for B's agents). There are now four games. In each game A chooses an alement x of X and b chooses an element y of Y, after which:

- In game I.a, A wins if x and y share a slot, otherwise B wins (in this game, A tries to force at least one meeting)
- In game I.b, A receives a positive payoff equivalent to the number of common slots in x and y (in this game, A tries to maximize the number of meetings)
- In game II.a, A wins if x and y do not share a slot, otherwise B wins (in this game, A tries to avoid any meetings)
- In game II.b, A receives a negative payoff equivalent to the number of common slots in x and y (in this game, A tries to minimize the number of meetings)

All these games can be analyzed using standard game-theoretic techniques. We focus on game I.a and leave the rest as an exercise to the reader. If there is an element y of Y available such that no x in X shares a slot with y, B chooses y and wins; so assume not, i.e. assume that every y in Y corresponds to at least one x in X such that x and y share a slot. A cannot play by any deterministic strategy, because B can counter it by choosing an y that does not share a slot with the deterministically chosen x; therefore A has to play by a mixed strategy, i.e. a randomized strategy exactly in the same way as the mixed strategy 1/3 - 1/3 - 1/3 is optimal for Roshambo (rock-paper-scissors). B will be also playing a mixed strategy in response. The probabilities of different elements of X and Y are dictated by the number of matching sets, i.e. an elements x of X that has common slots with many Y's is going to have a higher probability in the mixed strategy than those that have common slots with only a few Y's.

Calculating the stable mixed strategies (a Nash equilibrium for this game) is in theory straightforward and any basic reference on game theory can be consulted.

Comment: -1. The OP has provided a simple example in which it does matter whitch slots player A selects.

Comment: "I know ... all their possible (legal) moves." - B are not free to choose any available slot and the legal slots to B are known to A, this information allows you to make a more informed (better) choice of move than random.

Comment: Well yes but the B player will put as many agents as possible to slots that are not accessible to A. The only thing that matters is the intersection of locations available to both agents, and there the choice is random.

Comment: *"the B player will put as many agents as possible to slots that are not accessible to A"*. Uh? Not really... which part of the question and comments give you that impression?

Comment: Well if the goal of A is to maximize "meetings" with B then the correct strategy for B is to minimize the number of agents B has placed in slots that A can access at all... it is a counter example to the OP's assumption that B will play "random". B won't play by random if B is played by a human who wants to maximize the chances of avoiding meetings with agents A. It sounds like zero-sum game from the description to me.

Comment: *"if the goal of A is to maximize meetings with B then..."* Uh? Not really... which part of the question and comments give you that impression?

Comment: LOL this is getting weird, I'll rewrite the answer, but as an edit so that I can maintain my so far -4 score...

Comment: @antti.huima I think you're missing the part where not every agent can visit every site. For the rock-paper-scissors analogy, this means if B can only be rock or paper, then A should pick scissors to minimize the chance that they do the same thing. The restriction on who can go to what sites is what makes the problem subtle.

Comment: @antti.huima - You are also missing that the "best move" could either maximise or minimise the number of meetings (depending on other game conditions), not only maximising.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the answer just to focus on the structure of the game itself. It's not an algorithm per se as solving the game in explicit matrix form wouldn't be practical for large instances. Anyway, most likely this will my most down-voted answer so that's kind of an achievement.

Comment: @antti.huima - Interesting. However one of the assumptions is inaccurate: *"From this we deduce that if it is the goal of A to maximize [minimize] the number of meetings with agents of B, then it is the goal of B to minimize [maximize] the number of meetings with agents of A."*. This is not necessarily the case. Since the question was conceived as a question **about programming**, I did not focus on the details of the game, but in fact what I called "team B" is several teams, and each of them might try to max.e or min.e the amount of meetings independently from other players.

Comment: Before somebody asks: one of the possible slots for each agent always correspond to a non-move. If two agents try to occupy the same slot, they will stay in place, so even if team B is in reality C+D+E, the basic rule of only one player from team B moving to a slot is upheld (in reality is even more complex than this, but my point was not really discussing the game but the algorithm to find a fast way to compute the set of moves for A! :)

Comment: @mac Yes, but if you want to compute the "best" set of moves for A it must be one that maximizes the game-theoretic payoff for A assuming best move from B. That's how zero-sum game AI works, and normally it's implemented using techniques such as minimax, negamax, alpha-beta pruning, iterative deepening, proof number search, monte carlo UCT, and others (it's just a list of keywords to google for...) Of course you can compute fast SOME set of moves for A, but game-theoretically best moves must assume best response from B. See also: microeconomics, Nash equilibrium, and adversarial planning.

Comment: @antti.huima Thanks for the keywords! :) I agree that there is a BIG difference between computing the best moves against an opponent's strategy and the best moves against a random set of moves... When I will have implemented a solution I will be able to tell if the approximation "many unpredictable (and possibly sub-optimal) strategies = one random set of moves" is accurate enough for me to get a gain by calculating the best counter-moves against it. :)

Comment: @mac Yes... in general, planning against a random opponent is called planning against nature or against environment, and it is very different from planning against an opponent who is actively trying to win a game.